# Insert time in Oracle SQL using GregorianCalendar in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, timestamp, gregorian-calendar

In my oracle SQL table, I have a column that is default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, which I believe returns timestamp with timezone. I want to update this column by using GregorianCalendar object. I tried this to see what it returns:

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
System.out.println("                             date is: " + date.getTime());
```

**date.getTime()** returns `Thu Aug 27 19:50:34 EDT 2020`, but I am not sure if this is right format. I believe it is supposed to be something like `1960-01-01 23:03:20`

What is the right format to update timestamp column and how do I use GregorianCalendar object to create timestamp that has the right format for Oracle SQL timestamp type?

Comment: There is no right or wrong *format*, because you'll be sending the date *value* when you call `setTimestamp()` on the `PreparedStatement` used to execute the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` SQL statement, not a formatted string representing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `current_timestamp` returns the data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, so your problem is not the *format* of the timestamp, but to find the proper *class* which is

`oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ`

and the corresponding setter is

[`setTIMESTAMPTZ`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OraclePreparedStatement.html#setTIMESTAMPTZ_int__oracle_sql_TIMESTAMPTZ_)

Snipped below converts first the calendar to the `java.sql.Timestamp` and than to `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ`

Note that the `current_timestamp` uses the *time zone of the connected session*, so if you want to implement the same logic, you can add the relevant time zone in the constructor of the `GregorianCalendar`

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8"))
Timestamp tst = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis())

def stmt = con.prepareStatement("update tab set  curr_tst = ?")
stmt.setTIMESTAMPTZ(1,new oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ(con,tst,cal))
stmt.executeUpdate()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a `ZonedDateTime` from your `GregorianCalendar`  and use that directly as  parameter to a `PreparedStatement`:

```java
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8"));
ZonedDateTime zdt = cal.toZonedDateTime();
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("update the_table set the_column = ? where id = ?");
pstmt.setObject(1, zdt);
pstmt.setInt(2, 42);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Huh, this seems even *simpler* than the accepted answer, *doesn't use Oracle classes* and *works*!